# OSMC won't boot anymore after update

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbmc

At home I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with OSMC installed on it.
For those who don't know what it is, it's basically Kodi as an OS. It's a Debian based Linux OS with the Kodi software on top. So perhaps people who don't know OSMC but do know a lot about Linux will be able to answer my question.

After a few updates I rebooted the RPi2 and I couldn't boot into OSMC anymore. The screen went all black with just 3 lines of text on the screen:

> grep: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> grep: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> /sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm sorry I can't provide you more information but I'm not too familiar with Linux (except for really basic stuff). If you guys need to see something like files or something, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
When the aforementioned black screen appears I can't SSH into the system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same thing, solved it as follows:

1. Put the microSD in a USB reader and plug it into a linux pc (or use
   a VM/livecd).
2. Copy the /home/osmc/.kodi folder to somewhere else
3. Reinstall OSMC on the microSD card (through the installer on the
   OSMC webiste)
4. Plug the microSD into the Pi, let it do it's first boot/install
5. Plug the microSD back into the linux pc/VM/livecd and copy the .kodi
   folder back

Voila!

Comment: The thing I did now (my microSD has the NOOBS setup thing) was just reinstall it and don't do the update. I know it's a bit lame but I was tired of it breaking over and over again so I'm sticking with this for a while. It works good enough for what I want so I probably don't need the update anyway. Thanks anyway!